# simple Laravel View::make() not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

So I'm learning some basic Laravel stuff as I am new to PHP. 
I am following a basic tutorial that is having me print stuff to a file named `home.blade.php`.

The way I am calling it now is as follows.

Here is my `routes.php`

```
Route::get('/', array(
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@home'
));
```

Here is my `HomeController.php`

```
class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function home() {
        return View::make('home');
    }

}
```

Here is `home.blade.php`

```
{{'Hello.'}}
```

Before you ask, yes my home.blade.php is inside of my Views folder.

The error print out is as follows

```
FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 6:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\View' not found
in HomeController.php line 6
at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError(array('type' => '1', 'message' => 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\View' not found', 'file' => '/Users/ryandushane/Google Drive/Web_WorkSpace/theNeonSurf/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php', 'line' => '6')) in compiled.php line 1738
at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
```

Here's the odd part. If I change my `routes.php` to simply contain

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('home');
});
```

it functions fine.

Does anyone have an idea of what I could do?

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**New syntax for Laravel 5**

```
public function home() {
    return view('home');
}
```

For more information you can read it from here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views

Comment: Ahhh. Makes sense. A lot of their documentation still shows `View::make()` which is why I was confused.

Answer (score 4):

Try this in your top of the class(controller)

```
use View;
```

Answer (score 1):

I bet your controller class has a namespace, yes? Try `\View::make('home');` Or you can import it in the top of the file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use View;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function home() {
        return View::make('home');
    }

}
```

Comment: can you tell me why this works? You're correct. thanks for you're help! is this new in Laravel 5? (the tutorial I'm following is from Laravel 4)

Comment: It's not new for laravel 5. When you are inside a namespace in php, all classes outside of the namespace need to be prefixed with "\" or need to be imported with the `use` statement. Without the "\", you were actually saying class `App\View` which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: doing `return \View::make('home');` works. However `use View;` does not.